# How do we refer to etc package from NixOS configuration?

Tags: nix, nixos, pppd

I want to get a path, which leads to nixos `/etc` location (any one of `/run/current-system/etc` or `/nix/store/hashhere-etc-1.0`). I use this path to configure `pppd connect` script, some kind of the following,

```
  environment.etc."huawei" =
    { text = ''
        /dev/ttyUSB0
        38400
        lock
        crtscts
        nodetach
        noipdefault
        # Below here what I've struggled
        connect ${pkgs.etc}/${environment.etc."huawei-script".target}
      '';
      mode = "0777";
      target = "ppp/peers/huawei"; };
```

I have tried to write `${pkgs.etc}` or `${system.build.etc}` or even `${environment.etc}` resulting errors.

The directory structure is actually relative, but I think it's safer to use absolute path.

```
    /nix/store/...etc.../ppp/peers
    |- huawei
    |- huawei.d
       |- huawei.sh
       |- huawei.chat
```

Comment: btw, you don't have to specify `target`. You can embed it into name, like this:
`environment.etc."ppp/peers/huawei".text = "...";`. Implementation - https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/release-16.09/nixos/modules/system/etc/etc.nix#L114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem is you simply need to pass the string value of the `target` attribute to the `huawei.text connect` directive. As per the description for the [target attribute](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html#opt-environment.etc._name__.target) the value is a path relative to `/etc` so you should be able to either:

1. Make the value of the connect directive the string literal  `connect /etc/ppp/peers/huawei` or
2. make the `etc.huawei`attribute set a [recursive](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-constructs) one so that the attributes can refer to each other then do

   ```
   environment.etc.huawei = rec {
       target = "ppp/peers/huawei";
       text = ''...
                # Below here what I've struggled
                connect ${target}
       '';
   };
   ```

Comment: The main problem is actually where the correct path of `etc` (since in NixOS, `etc` folder is not below the root). How do I get those path to absolutely locate my script (which is in `etc`).

Comment: @Abdillah why do you think `etc` isn't under root? I tried `ls -la /` and `etc` is there. It isn't even a symlink.

Comment: @danbst Oh no... Yes you're right! It seems I overthink it :(

Comment: Thanks @nickbh , your #1 suggestion is thus correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to path to file in `/nix/store/...etc...` like this:

```
{ config, pkgs, lib, ... }:

{
  environment.etc."test".text = "helo";
  environment.etc."test2".text = "${config.environment.etc."test".source.outPath}";
}
```

Now I have in `/etc/test2`:

```
$ cat /etc/test2
/nix/store/1igc2rf011jmrr3cprsgbdp3hhm5d4l0-etc-test
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case, it doesn't have source. But thanks!

Comment: have you tried that out? `source` attribute is created implicitly when you set `text` (https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/release-16.09/nixos/modules/system/etc/etc.nix#L115).

Comment: ah, I've fixed the code example. The culprit was to refernce via `config` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was overlook a fact where NixOS actually map any files in `/nix/store/...etc../` into the `/etc` itself.

So, to refer to a file, it is better to use `/etc` directly.

```
connect /etc/${environment.etc."huawei-script".target}
```